# How to create an extension method for any type of Enum array in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, enums, extension-methods

Below is the code I have but the method is not available on Enum arrays. I can't work out what I'm doing wrong. Note that I'm  unable to test the line `Array.ConvertAll` until I have this method available on Enum arrays.

```
Public Module EnumExtensions

    <Extension()>
    Function ValuesToString(Source As [Enum]()) As String()

        Dim EnumType = Source.GetType()
        If Not EnumType.IsEnum Then Return Nothing

        Return Array.ConvertAll(Source, Function(x) x.ToString)

    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: What are you doing with an `enum` array? Also look into `IConvertable`...

Comment: I need the `enum` array values as a string array.

Comment: If all you're going to do is call `Array.ConvertAll` then why do you need to restrict it to just an `Enum`?

Comment: My objective is to convert an array of `enum` values to a string array. I don't know whether `Array.ConvertAll` is the best way to go about doing that. I haven't tested this code, it will probably give me an integer array instead of the text representation. What do you suggest?

Comment: You could just call `myArray.Select(Function(e) e.ToString()).ToArray()`. That will work on any array.

Comment: If I put `myArray.Select(Function(e) e.ToString()).ToArray()` in a function, what type will `myArray` be? `Array` type does not work.

Comment: Um, `myArray` would be an array. It will work with an array of `Enum` values and it will work with any other array too.  In fcat, it will work with any object whose type implements `IEnumerable(Of T)`. If you're suggesting that you actually have an instance of the `Array` class then you shouldn't, because there is rarely a reason to instantiate that type directly.

Comment: That said, you could still do basically the same thing with an `Array` instance but you'd have to call `Cast` before `Select`.  That's because `Array` implements `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable(Of T)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you could just call `Select` and `ToArray` as needed.  If you really want an extension though, you would need to make your method generic:

```
<Extension>
Public Function ToStrings(Of T)(source As T()) As String()
    'If Not GetType(T).IsEnum Then
    '    Return Nothing
    'End If

    Return Array.ConvertAll(source, Function(e) e.ToString())
End Function
```

There's no generic constraint that can limit that method to be called on just an array of `Enum` values so you can use an `If` statement to either return `Nothing` or throw an exception.  I don't really see the point though, as it really doesn't hurt if you allow the same method to be called on another array of any other type anyway.

Comment: It ***could*** be more generic if the return wasn't constrained to a `String` array, what if I wanted a int or long array etc...?

Comment: Then you'd be in a different situation to the OP, who specifically said that they want a `String` array. If you want to be able to decide the output type on an ad hoc basis then it seems clear that calling `Select` and `ToArray` as required would be a logical choice, because the `Select` method then knows exactly what type the items are and using `Cint` or `CLng` to convert the `Enum` values to numbers would simple and sensible.